# ClangFormat weird behavior

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am using the following setting:

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 2, TabWidth: 2, BreakBeforeBraces: Attach, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -2 }",
```

Without `+` on lambda, it looks correct.

```
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, [](void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, std::string *stream) -> size_t {
        auto s_size = size * count;
        stream->append((char *)buffer, 0, s_size);
        return s_size;
      });
```

After adding the plus sign on the lambda, it gets formatted wrong. (I need the `+`).

```
  curl_easy_setopt(
      curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, +[](void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, std::string *stream) -> size_t {
        auto s_size = size * count;
        stream->append((char *)buffer, 0, s_size);
        return s_size;
      });
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: `+lambda expression` is usually to trigger conversion to function pointer, but isnt this done implicitly already by just passing it to the function that expects a function pointer?

Comment: Cast to `curl_write_callback` or `void*` instead of `+`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai `curl_easy_setopt` is a C variadic function.